# Windows package installer for automatic setup

Tags: batch-file, scripting, installation, package, windows-installer

All,

I have a package that should be easily deployed on any client machine, say provided there is Windows as an OS.

Package contains icons, .dll, doc files, .xml templates, .py scripts...

I would like that the User unzip this folder anywhere, launch a .bat or any other script, and that package is copied pasted at the right place.

In a second phase, i could refine this installer deplacing some files at the right place.

Is it possible with a .bat file ? What would it look like ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type in Start - Run

```
iexpress
```

and follow the prompts in the IExpress 2.0 Setup Wizard.

Comment: iexpress is a tool to build the installer, but you do not say how i should right the script or batch file to cut-paste the folder at the right place on the client machine...